# How would a client/server utilizing UPnP work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, networking, client-server, upnp, drb

I'd like to allow two computers behind routers share files in a server/client setup using Ruby; I've looked into the [UPnP implementation](http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/UPnP/) for Ruby, but the documentation is, in my opinion, fairly poor and it does not offer much of an explanation of the library. Can someone give a basic example of how a server and client, both behind routers, would work utilizing UPnP with, preferably, DRB?

Thanks!